# How do I detect triangle edge and access the two vertices that form it?

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

I've seen other questions about only drawing fragments on the triangle edges using barycentric coordinates, but I need more than that and I wonder if there should be another approach.

This is basically a shadow map render and I want to write some additional results to the FBO color attachment. (Namely the light origin - edge vertices plane equation).

I can easily do this via a geometry shader converting triangles to lines but it's not pixel-to-pixel exact to the triangle edge. And it's also causing depth fighting that I can't accept.

I was hoping for a trick in a fragment shader that I can somehow render triangles and get the edge vertex coordinates in there.

Comment: This question is almost unclear. As far as I understand you want to render triangle primitives and in the fragment shader you want to know the 3 vertex coordinates of the triangle where the fragment is on. If so, then use a [Geometry Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader). In the geometry shader you have access to the vertex coordinates and you can pass them to the Fragment shader, by using the [Interpolation qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers) `flat`, which causes that the coordinates will not be interpolated.

Comment: @Rabbid76, I want to only draw edges, and for each edge fragment, know which two triangle vertices that edge connects.